# Swift - ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback

Tags: swift, abaddressbook

I am trying to register an address book change callback in swift but can't seem to find how to do it. I know how do get a notification on address book change for iOS 9 but I need for iOS 8 as well.

```
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *)
    {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "addressBookDidChange:", name: CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        // What goes here?
    }
```

I do understand I need to use `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback` but I can't find a way how to call a function from it.

Thank You for any help